# Extract or get parameters from url in Gatling

Tags: load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

In Gatling how do I proceed to extract or get and save the Url parameters from response body?
I make a post request and as response body a I got a link with parameters (**pstId** & **autId**) that I would like to extract and save them:

```
    /**** HTTP Calls ****/
    def getResource() = {
        exec(
            http("psu initiates payment")
              .post("/v1/payments/pain.001-sepa-credit-transfers/")
              .headers(Map("x-request-id" -> "UUID.randomUUID()", "usp": -> "8975" ))
              .body(ElFileBody(XML_FILE_BODY)).asXml
              .check(jsonPath("$._links[:1].linkRedirect").find.transform({s => pstId = s; s}).saveAs("pstId"))
              .check(jsonPath("$._links[:1].linkRedirect").find.transform({s => autId = s; s}).saveAs("autId"))
        )
    }
```

the structure of the response look like:

```
{
"_links": {
        "linkRedirect": "http://localhost:8200/pis?pstId=G0w6I2OTaPFlwzU19xk1dRqwmVyHOw0xIA3YvYQiBEeoJDY7Bl-O1-YQfSBdw5ZIGdR5pO_&autId=c27aad0e-7c9c6f465237",
        "scaOAuth": null,
        "selectId": null
}
```

Thank you for sharing you ideas and knowledge with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes from `io.gatling.http.client` package.
Example code for `autId` is:

```java
    import io.gatling.http.client.uri.Uri;
    import io.gatling.http.client.Param;

    ...

    .check(jsonPath("$._links[:1].linkRedirect").transform(s -> {
        Uri uri =  Uri.create(s);
        List<Param> prms = uri.getEncodedQueryParams();
        for(int i=0; i<prms.size(); i++) {
        Param p = prms.get(i);
        if (p.getName() == "autId") {
            return p.getValue();
        }
        }
        return ""; // autId parameter is not found
    }).saveAs("autId"))
```